Select option based on condition fulfilment in Angular
Here's my HTML form:
<select [(ngModel)]="bill.payMode">
  <option value="credit" *ngIf="pay._id">Credit</option>
  <option value="cash">Cash</option>
  <option value="card">Card</option>
</select>

Here's my TS file:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bill.payMode = 'cash';
}

I want to put an if-else condition in the TS file wherein, if pay._id is fulfilled, the default option shown is credit and not cash.
Note that credit is hidden if pay._id is not fulfilled.
How can I go about this?
I tried this without success:
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(pay._id) {
      this.bill.payMode = 'cash';
    } else {
      this.bill.payMode = 'credit';
    }


how does this.bill  and pay values gets to the comopnent

can u plz provide more code

first add this in the headers
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
// -> add in "imports" : [FormsModule],

in class :
choices = [
    {
        "id" : "",
        "wording" : `--- no selection ---`,
    },
    {
        "id" : "d1",
        "wording" : `1st choice`,
    },
    {
        "id" : "c2",
        "wording" : `2nd choice`,
    },
    
];

selected_choice = "d1";

and in html :
<select [(ngModel)]="selected_choice">
    
    <ng-template
        ngFor
        let-choice
        [ngForOf]="choices"
    >
        <option
            value="{{choice.id}}"
        >
            {{choice.wording}}
        </option>
    </ng-template>
    
</select>


<div>
    {{selected_choice}}
</div>

